# Vue function toggle works one time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to change the icon on click whenever the state of paused changes:

```
<div @click="playPause1()" v-bind:class="[paused ? 'icon-pause' : 'icon-play']"></div>
```

And my script is the following:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      paused: false,
    }
  },

  methods: {
   playPause1(event) {
    if (this.paused == true) {
      this.audio_player_1.play();
    } else {
      this.audio_player_1.pause(); 
    }
    this.paused = !this.paused;
    console.log(this.paused);
   },
  } 
};
```

This works for me once, I click, the icon class switches and get the other icon, but I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_wrapper' of undefined
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Full code:

```
<template>
<v-ons-page>
  <v-ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Mixer</div>
  </v-ons-toolbar>

  <v-ons-list>
    <v-ons-list-item>
      <label class="left">
       <v-ons-checkbox> </v-ons-checkbox>
         Activate CheckBox
      </label>
    </v-ons-list-item>
  </v-ons-list>

   <!-- Microphone card -->
   <v-ons-card>
      <v-ons-icon icon="icon-mic" size="20px">
        <div class="title">Microphone</div>
      </v-ons-icon>
      <div class="content">
        <v-ons-range v-model="mic_volume" style="width: 50%;"></v-ons-range>
      </div>
    </v-ons-card>
     
     <!-- audio file 1 card -->
     <v-ons-card>
      <v-ons-row>
       <v-ons-col>

          <v-ons-icon icon="icon-round-mute" size="20px">
            <v-ons-input type="file" v-model="audio_file_1" @change="Audio1change"> </v-ons-input>
          </v-ons-icon>
        </v-ons-col>
      </v-ons-row>
        <br/>
        <v-ons-row>
          <v-ons-col>
          <v-ons-range v-model="audio_file_1_volume" style="width: 50%;"></v-ons-range>
          </v-ons-col>
        </v-ons-row>
        <br/><br/>
        <v-ons-row>
          <v-ons-col width="25%">
            <v-ons-icon icon="icon-headphone" v-on:click="muteUnmute1()"></v-ons-icon>
          </v-ons-col>
          <v-ons-col  width="25%">

            <div @click="playPause()" v-bind:class="[isPaused ? 'icon-pause' : 'icon-play']">
            </div>
            <!-- <div :class="playPauseState1" @click="playPause1()"></div> -->
            <!-- <v-ons-icon v-bind:icon="[paused ? 'icon-pause' : 'icon-play']" @click="playPause1" v-bind="$attrs" ></v-ons-icon> -->
          </v-ons-col>
          <v-ons-col  width="25%">
            <v-ons-icon icon="icon-loop" v-on:click="loop1"></v-ons-icon>
          </v-ons-col>
        </v-ons-row>

    </v-ons-card>
    <!-- Audio file 2 card -->
     <v-ons-card>
         <v-ons-row>
          <v-ons-col>
           <v-ons-input type="file" v-model="audio_file_2" @change="Audio2change" accept="audio/*"> </v-ons-input>
         </v-ons-col>
        </v-ons-row>
        <v-ons-row>
         <v-ons-col>
           <v-ons-icon icon="icon-round-mute" size="20px">
           </v-ons-icon>
           <v-ons-range v-model="audio_file_2_volume" style="width: 50%;"></v-ons-range>
          </v-ons-col>
        </v-ons-row>
        <br/><br/>

        <v-ons-row>
          <v-ons-col width="25%">
            <v-ons-icon icon="icon-headphone" v-on:click="muteUnmute2"></v-ons-icon>
          </v-ons-col>
          <v-ons-col  width="25%">
            <v-ons-icon icon="icon-play" v-on:click="playPause2"></v-ons-icon>
          </v-ons-col>
          <v-ons-col  width="25%">
            <v-ons-icon icon="icon-loop" v-on:click="loop2"></v-ons-icon>
          </v-ons-col>
        </v-ons-row>
      
    </v-ons-card>
</v-ons-page>
</template>

<script>



export default {
  data() {
    return {
      mic_volume: 25,
      audio_file_1_volume: 25,
      audio_file_2_volume: 25,
      audio_player_1: new Audio(),
      audio_player_2: new Audio(),
      isPaused: true,
    }
     
  },

  methods: {
   Audio1change(event) {

      var fileReader  = new FileReader;
      fileReader.onload = function(){
         var arrayBuffer = this.result;
         console.log(arrayBuffer);
      }

      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]); 
      this.audio_player_1.src = url;
      this.audio_player_1.play();
   },

   Audio2change(event) {
      var fileReader  = new FileReader;
      fileReader.onload = function(){
         var arrayBuffer = this.result;
         console.log(arrayBuffer);
      }

      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
      this.audio_player_2.src = url; 
      this.audio_player_2.play();
   },

   muteUnmute1: function(){ this.audio_player_1.muted ^= true},
   muteUnmute2: function(){ this.audio_player_2.muted ^= true },

   playPause1: function(event){
    console.log("clicked");
    console.log(this.isPaused);
    if(this.$data.isPaused == true){
      this.$data.isPaused = false
      console.log(this.isPaused);
    }
    if(this.$data.isPaused == false){
      this.$data.isPaused = true
      console.log(this.isPaused);

    }
    

   },
   playPause2: function(event){
     this.audio_player_2.play();
   }
} 
};

</script>

<style scoped>
.button-margin {
  margin: 6px 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Kindly show the <style></style> code

Comment: .icon-pause:before {
  content: "\e9c2";
  color: #7b7b7b;
}
.icon-play:before {
  content: "\e9c3";
  color: #7b7b7b;
}

Comment: create a separate classes without pseudo selector, i.e. create `.icon-pause {} ` and `.icon-play {}` as standalone classes

Comment: That's not the problem, even with another classes without pseudo selectors. The issue is with VueJS not CSS

Comment: `Cannot read property '_wrapper' of undefined` simply this error means that there's a typo mistake and the vue could not match something within the vue to class, but  your code seems to has no such a bug, if you did not show the full code, kindly edit the question with full code snippet

Comment: I just did, can you take a look please ?

Comment: You don't need to use `this.$data`, you can just do `this.isPaused`

Comment: Adding `playPause()` would solve the whole issue as @Daniel_Knights mentioned

Comment: Also, you can simplify things greatly by removing the `playPause1` method and, in your click handler, do this: `@click="isPaused = !isPaused"`